# Cannot load file or assembly System.Web.WebPages.Deployment with all pre-existing VS projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I recently setup a new Windows 10 workstation , imported my IIS settings from previous windows 10 IIS.

Everything is setup correctly with IIS, however everytime I run a new project I get an error about Missing System.Web.WebPages.Deployment :

```
   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0
```

The fix is simple, I just add the following to the web config.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-X.X.X.X" newVersion="X.X.X.X"/>
  </dependentAssembly>        
</assemblyBinding>
```

The problem is that now just because I'm having an issue I'm forcing a checkout on all projects and questions from other developers all of which do not have this issue.  I've attempted to re-register .net framework like I did back in the day, however that's now part of Windows 10 to include 4.6.2

This is happening on older ASP.NET WebForms written in VS2013 with a mix of newer MVC apps written in VS 2015.

I've found nothing to address a System wide issue with this assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll on your BIN folder.